# Is there a way for turtle.textinput() to prompt in a specific coordinate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm using turtle.textinput() to get a user input in turtle and I want the prompt to appear in (0,0) or within the turtle screen. I'd like to know if it's a possible task or not because it is a separate prompt/screen.

Here is a sample code for it:

```
import turtle
from turtle import*

t1 = turtle.Turtle()

def buttonClick(x,y):

    user_inp = turtle.textinput("Test input", "put name here")
#then place a code here to set user_inp pos to (0,0)
    print(user_inp)
        
turtle.onscreenclick(buttonClick,1)
turtle.listen()

turtle.done()
```

So in conclusion my expected result is to have the user_inp prompt to appear in the (0,0) coordinate.

Comment: Good question, altough isn't 0,0 where the dialog appears by default? I think you'd have to dig into Tkinter to move it elsewhere. As an aside, `from turtle import*` can be removed.

Comment: On my end, the prompt appears outside of the turtle screen.

Thanks for the feedback, I'll take a look into Tkinter to solve this one.